# Firebase storage store url vs reference

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

For example I have Firestore object with images, how should I store the images?

Should i store `array` of string(`urls`) or `array` of `reference` to Firebase Storage (not sure if it possible, maybe reference as string)?

It feels like storing a `reference` is more flexible, for example we can create `reference` before the image is uploaded and we not depend on the `url` , but I wonder if it will be correct decision.

Comment: can you please a more detailed explanation about what you are trying to achieve

Comment: I have item that has images in Firebase storage, I wounder what is the correct way to structure the data, should it contain "download url" or reference to storage bucket

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong..!! You have some set of images stored in your firebase storage and now in you want to get the images to load directly in your recycler view or something other like you said a model. Is this correct?

Comment: I have "model" that represent some item and can contain images, user can add/delete images to it, so the set of images uploaded by user and can be deleted also

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By "storage reference" I'll assume you mean the path to the image in your storage bucket. Let's quickly define all three parts in play here:

1. Each file in a Cloud Storage bucket has a unique path within that bucket.
2. Each file in Cloud Storage can have a download URL. This URL allows anyone who knows it to **read** the file through HTTP (regardless of any security rules defined on the file).
3. To read/write a file through the SDK, you need to create a `StorageReference` to it, and have permission to read/write the file. From a reference to a file, you can get the download URL and the path to that file.

You can store #1 and/or #2 in a database, but you can't store #3 as references only exist in your application code.

Most commonly you'll see the download URL being shared, as that is the most familiar way to share files with others. And from the download URL, you can always create a reference, and thus also get the path.

You can also just store the path of the file, and then get the download URL as needed. This is slightly less common, as it requires that all users have full read access to the storage bucket, which isn't needed if you share download URLs directly.

I occasionally store both the path **and** the download URL for the image, to that both are loaded in one go. While either one can easily be mapped to the other, storing both removes the need for that mapping and keeps my code simpler. From how I phrase things I hope it's clear that this is a personal preference.

Comment: How do you store both `path` and `url` if you have list of images related to some item? do you use some mediator collection of images Image<path,url> ?

Comment: For each image in that list, you'd store the path and download URL. In JSON that could be something like `images: [ { path: "/path/to/image.jpg", downloadURL: "https://....../image.jpg?token=....." }, { path: "/path/to/image2.jpg", downloadURL: "https://....../image2.jpg?token=....." } ]`.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your implementation.

- If you are using Firebase Storage API to get image then store reference.
- If you want to use Glide/Picasso then store URL

Note : Reference is more secure.